# Does executing as a script mean all my fields become data type of VARCHAR2?

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I'm running a script in Toad for Oracle. I have two main options to run the script:

Hotkey <kbd>F9</kbd>: Execute Statement
Hotkey <kbd>F5</kbd>: Execute as Script

"Execute Statement" will return my fields with the data type that I expect them to be (e.g. NUMBER fields output as NUMBER fields).

But "Execute as Script" is returning all my fields with the VARCHAR2 data type. Even fields which are definitely NUMBER data type end up as VARCHAR2. I can literally run the same script with F9 and then F5 and see that it returns different data types.

So my first question is whether or not this is behaving as intended. And, if it is intended, then my second question is how I can avoid having all my data types be VARCHAR2 when using "Execute as Script". I need to use "Execute as Script" because I'm using bind variables.

Edit: For example, if I had a table like this:

```
TBL_PAID_DATA

╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ employee ║ paid_amt ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║ Sam      ║     1500 ║
║ Sam      ║      200 ║
║ Sam      ║      150 ║
║ Lisa     ║      500 ║
║ Lisa     ║      430 ║
║ Bart     ║      700 ║
║ Donald   ║      840 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

And had a script like this:

```
SELECT employee, sum(paid_amt)
FROM TBL_PAID_DATA
GROUP BY employee
```

Then the employee field returns as VARCHAR2 both when I "Execute as Script" and "Execute Statement". However, sum(paid_amt) returns as a VARCHAR2 when I "Execute as Script" and a NUMBER when I "Execute Statement". I would've expected sum(paid_amt) to return with NUMBER data type always.

Comment: what do you mean by "returning all my fields"?  what is your script doing? (dbms_output? inserting to database?)  Can you show the code?

Comment: At a guess - "Execute Statement" is returning a result set to Toad which it is then displaying in its UI using its own formatting. "Execute as Script" is being executed in an SQL/Plus style environment and Oracle is formatting the output and is returning the console output as a string.

Comment: What happens if you add a [column formatting directive](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm) before you query when you run it as a script? If you have a `SALARY` column then try putting this on the line before the query `COLUMN SALARY FORMAT $99,990.00` and see if it changes the output.

Comment: @tbone Apologies. I've edited my question to include some dummy data and a query to give context to what I'm talking about.

Comment: How are you finding the data type of the columns when you execute it as a script?

Comment: sorry, i must need more coffee.  You say sum(paid_amt) "returns" as a varchar2.  Are you selecting into a variable using pl/sql?  Are you simply outputting to console (script output)?  Where are you returning, and where do you see this labeled as varchar2 exactly?

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for the idea. I just tried using a column formatting directive and, while it did change the formatting in the data grid, the data type still is VARCHAR2 and not NUMBER.

Comment: @tbone Sorry if I'm misusing terminology here. Does it suffice to say that when I run this query the data type of sum(paid_amt) will be VARCHAR2 or NUMBER depending on whether I run with F5 or F9? The entire query can be seen in my question. I see the data types by using the "Export Dataset..." wizard and clicking 'Data Masking...' at the bottom left of the wizard's window. My number fields being data type VARCHAR2 is an issue for me since I need to export this data to Excel and I can't easily perform calculations on numbers stored as text in Excel.

Comment: @MT0 I'm finding the data type by using the "Export Data..." set wizard. There's a button called "Data Masking..." at the bottom left of the screen and it gives the data type for each field. I also see my numeric fields being exported to Excel as text columns by using this same "Export Data..." wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is so because <kbd>F5</kbd> Executes as script, so result is collected from `sqlplus` as text.

So a solution is to copy/paste your result to text file and use a csv-import tool like Open-office Calc, where you can convert your data to numeric and do further calculation.

Comment: Thank you for this response. Just one editorial note: I think you mean F5. I just tried your suggestion and I can confirm it works. I exported the output to a tab delimited .txt file and used Excel's import txt wizard. This is a solution, but it isn't as elegant as I'd hope. I was hoping I could solve this from Toad rather than having to do a bit of a manual step in Excel every time I want to export data. I will just wait around to see if anyone else has other ideas, but if I don't see any soon then I'll accept yours as the answer.